# django models design for ride share application, suggestions pls

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models, database-schema

I am working on a ride share application. I need help on designing the models for private messages.

I have designed the below models, its look like complex in querying them in views. can You guys specify a better and easy one.

```
class Ride(models.Model):   
    type = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    add_source = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='source')
    add_destination = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='destination')
    ride_startDateTime = models.DateTimeField(default= datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)
    ride_startPref = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICES, default='None')

class Conversation(models.Model):
    ride_id = models.ForeignKey(Ride)

class Messages(models.Model):
    conversation_id = models.ForeignKey(Conversation)
    ride_id = models.ForeignKey(Ride)
    sender_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender')
    receiver_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='receiver')
    Content = models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default= datetime.datetime.now, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
```

User model is django inbuilt.
Please consider the following use cases:

1) A Conversation has to integrate with Ride, 
   For Ex: User X is a owner of ride 3, User Y can contact X for this ride(3), then the new conversation id(77) will be generated. After that whatever messages sent between them should be under the same conversation id(77). 
If another user Z is trying to contact the user X for the same ride 3, then a new conversation ID(33) has to generated.

2) If the user X having another ride called 4, then if user Y contact the User X through the other ride means, it has to generate new conversation id(99) and all the messages sent between them on the ride should come under the same conversation id(99).

Answer (score 0):

Compare with:

```
class Ride(models.Model):   
    type = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    source_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='rides_from')
    destination_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='rides_to')
    started_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    start_pref = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICES, default='None')

class Conversation(models.Model):
    ride = models.ForeignKey(Ride)
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='conversations_as_user1')
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='conversations_as_user2')

class Message(models.Model):
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation)
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    posted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)
```

Keep in mind that whenever wither sender or receiver is deleting a message, it is deleted for both of them.